# How do I assign an object to a member class in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp

I am building a tour application. I have bookings which point to a tour modality but I haven't been able to assign the book modality when adding a new booking using JSLT.
Here's my JSP code:

```
<c:forEach items="${modalities}" var="modality">
                <form:form method="POST" action="/book_tour" modelAttribute="booking">
                    <p>${modality.name}</p>
                    <jsp:setProperty name="booking" property="tourModality" value="${modality}"></jsp:setProperty>
                    <input name="modality" type="hidden" value="${modality}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:label path="calendarDate">Escoja una fecha</form:label>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                            <form:input path="calendarDate" type='text' class="form-control"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <form:label path="calendarDate">Hora: </form:label>
                            <form:select path="calendarDate">
                                <c:forEach items="${modality.tourHours}" var="tourHour">
                                    <option>${tourHour.timeSlot}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Reservar"/>
                </form:form>
```

Comment: What is your expected result and actual result?

Comment: A Modality has several Bookings. I want to assign the corresponding parent Modality object to the booking object.When I post the booking object in the form to the controller it has no Modality object. The corresponding modality is in the forEach loop.